# VBA to find Row number or Cell adress of the last row in the same column from multiple sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code for getting values of the last row of a particular column(Column A in this case) from all sheets of a workbook to the sheet "master".

```
Sub CopyToMaster()
ShtCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To ShtCount
Worksheets(i).Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
'Required after first paste to shift active cell down one
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Selection.PasteSpecial
Next I
End Sub
```

Now I want the cell address (e.g., Sheet1!A98) or at least the row number of the cells instead of values in the cells. I can do my work in half the time if this is possible. I can't find a solution because I know VB only through last one week's googling ;) Hope for a response ASAP. Thanks

Comment: You have the row in `LastRow` and for the address, you'd use `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) attribute and store it in a variable to have it pasted in the cell concatenated with the sheet it is referenced to.

Edited with Nathan_Sav's point, I added RowAbsolute and ColumnAbsolute to have a more flexible approach to referencing the cells from the different sheets.

Do note that you have to use the [.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215978%28v=office.11%29.aspx) of the sheet you have the data you want to make a reference to.

The following code does not require a lot of change:

```
Sub CopyToMaster()

Dim LastRow as Long, a as String

ShtCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To ShtCount
    Worksheets(i).Activate
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select

    'Storing the current location of the cell
    a = Selection.Address(RowAbsolute:= False, ColumnAbsolute:= False)

    Sheets("Master").Activate
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select

    'Required after first paste to shift active cell down one
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    ' Pasting in a formula the corresponding workbook it references to and the cell's position
    Selection.Formula = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!" & a
Next i

End Sub
```

Hope this sorts this out.

Comment: Pierre Chevallier  - You can turn the locking $'s off by using the arguments in Address, no need for replace.

Comment: Interesting I did not know, I'll take note of this for the future and edit the code above.

Comment: Works perfect. exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the cell address you can simply do the following:

```
Dim sAddress as String

For i = 2 to ShtCount
    'No need to select a sheet
    sAddress = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Address
Next i
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
Dim master_book As Workbook, ref_book As Workbook
Dim sh_cnt As Long, i As Long
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set ref = ThisWorkbook
' set the master workbook

sh_cnt = ref_book.Sheets.Count
For i = 1 To sh_cnt
    Set sheet = ref_book.Sheets(1)
    master_book.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i) = sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
Next
```